# Lock wait timeout exceeded while altering table

Tags: mysql, locking

I'm trying to `ALTER TABLE` on a table with 3 million rows, on a **local** development database on my PC. No other queries are running at the time, in fact i tried it just after restart.
The query runs with "copying to tmp table":
[image]
and in about 20 minutes, the query fails with

`ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

Which is strange, since this is the only query running I see in process list.

I tried to set `transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED`, i tried with `DISABLE KEY` before `ALTER` statement. `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` is 10.

I'm really puzzled with this. I don't want to drop the table or delete records as this is one of the main tables and there is lots of foreign keys defined on it.

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

This is fairly similar to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27496/mysql-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded) post, but no reason was found there.

Here is `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`:

```
=====================================
2021-04-02 12:57:50 0x7f11ec24a700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 21 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 1054 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 2955 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 4009
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 84139
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 73393
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 122971, OS waits 11295
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 4287078, OS waits 8693
RW-sx spins 1940, rounds 6499, OS waits 122
Spin rounds per wait: 122971.00 RW-shared, 4287078.00 RW-excl, 3.35 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 2838178
Purge done for trx's n:o < 2838178 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 0
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421190241873552, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421190241872632, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421190241871712, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
4419208 OS file reads, 5061062 OS file writes, 383134 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.14 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 3093, seg size 3095, 39551 merges
merged operations:
 insert 1871387, delete mark 14, delete 11
discarded operations:
 insert 93817, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34673, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 74791595141
Log flushed up to   74791595141
Pages flushed up to 74791595141
Last checkpoint at  74791595132
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
14348 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 137428992
Dictionary memory allocated 4328873
Buffer pool size   8191
Free buffers       1024
Database pages     7159
Old database pages 2622
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 215329, not young 11158813
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 4419104, created 145522, written 4838659
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 7159, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[25]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=1571, Main thread ID=139714966587136, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 3192025, updated 0, deleted 0, read 3193018
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I already created a copy and transferred records to new table so I can continue with my development. But this seem like a bug to me in MySQL.

I was adding a new column to the table, and it was exactly this error, as I was running this statement from console.

Comment: You should probably change in your configuration innodb_lock_wait_timeout back to the default of 50 (seconds) to give your machine a chance with this huge data table. And post the last 400 lines of your error log after getting timeout exceeded message, please. Consider ANALYZE TABLE tbl_name; prior to attempt to add column to ensure indexes are a fresh rebuild.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Rick James in a comment:

MySQL 8.0 with `ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=INSTANT` may allow `ADD COLUMN`.